# Where to place code shared between two pages in an ASP.NET Web Forms?

Tags: share, webforms, code-behind

I have an ASP.NET Web Forms application.

In this application I have a `Login.aspx` page with code behind. Now I would like to create `LoginLight.aspx` lightweight version of `Login.aspx` page. 
The light version should have less HTML content and should use the key functions of `Login.aspx.vb` code behind. These functions have a lot of code.

Therefore, in order not to have a lot of duplicate code, I would like to move the common functions to a common file. I was thinking about placing those functions in a class library in the `App_Code` folder but I read on the web that is not a good solution.

I also read that to have the same `code behind` for two different pages because it is not a good practice. How would I tackle this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Create a base page that has all the functionality that you want shared.

`Login.aspx` and `LoginLight.aspx` will both inherit that base page.

Comment: Did you end up implementing this answer? Did it help?